# include .as file inside .fla

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs3

i open up .fla file, but when i click window->action, there is not actionscript inside it.  may i know where else can i check the .fla file is importing .as file. where to check it in flash cs3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the Actions window only shows you script attached to the frame you've currently selected. Try opening Window -> Movie Explorer. This lets you browse all the contents (including scripts) contained in the movie (make sure the "show: ActionScript" button is selected). Then look through any scripts you find for #include statements that may refer to external AS files.

Note also that Flash objects can be attached to Classes, which will cause the .as file associated with the class to be imported. In the Library panel, check the "Linkage" column to see which objects have classes attached to them.