# Open the as (action script) from fla file

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder, red5, fla

The question can sound a little bit stupid, but I can't figure it out!
I have a fla file (http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/simpleBroadcaster.fla ) and I follow a tutorial to edit this file (http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/04/streaming-live-with-red5-media-server.html ) and I can't begin to step 2 because I can't find the file or folders.

Please, help. I downloaded the trials of both Flash builder and Flash Professional CS6 but still couldn't find it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415477/include-as-file-inside-fla) solution gives something empty. So I taught there should be some swc file ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272484/how-to-find-as-code-in-fla-file)) but I couldn't find it.

edit: I found the as file, it's not in the fla file but in a separate directory. I had to download the whole trunk. I found the file and can open and edit it in a texteditor. But I'd like to get it in Flashbuilder to compile at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 2.
Let's now open the "red5" directory that we checked out in FlashBuilder.
```

RED5! You need download and install "Red5 Media Server" http://www.red5.org/

```
Exploring Red5 Media Server
Download and install Red5 Media Server for your environment from here. Now it is time to implement a sweeping live stream between our two laptops.
```

Comment: Ofcourse I installed red5 first. Red5 was working very well. My question wasn't about that.
However, I solved my issue using JWplayer instead of changing the demo. Now I can go fullscreen too :-)